# Tomcat is ignoring Java Options when running as a service

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I'm trying to debug Tomcat while running as Windows Service (on Windows 7 64 bit).
The Tomcat instance starts just fine, but it seems to ignore any Java options (entered through the "Java" tab on the Tomcat manager window).

I know it ignores them because this line doesn't cause it to wait for a debugger, and the appropriate log line doesn't appear in catalina.log

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

Any advice?

P.S.

I installed this Tomcat instance by running the Windows installer [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi).

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.halcyon-solutions.com/2010/04/remote-debugging-apache-tomcat-on.html says

Make sure there are no spaces at the end of the lines when you specify these options in the window.

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yeah, I had these two on a single line. Damn life's little annoyances.